# casting struct from c into c++ class

Tags: c++, c, class, struct

I have a struct in c

```
struct account 
{
   int account_number;
   char *name;
   float balance;
};
```

Then I have different code in C++, which is linked to c code. There I have a class

```
class Account
{
  // some functions ...
  void print()
  {
    std::cout<<"bal-bla-bla"<< account<< std::end; 
  }

   private:
     int account_number;
     char *name;
     float balance;
};
```

Is it possible to cast info from struct into class? What is the best way of doing it? 
thanks!

Comment: You should make `class Account` have private member of type `account`, instead of repeating the items. Then you can use assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Derive your class from the C-struct.
Then you inherit the data members and you only need to add the methods.

```
class Account:
   struct account {
  ...
  void print( void ) {
     ....
  }
};
```

Comment: can not do this, because struct and class are in different libraries, which are in general supposed to be independent...

Comment: In your .cpp file you can surely include the header file from the .c struct and link to the C-based library? (I mean: the Account class and account struct can be in separate files just fine)

Comment: library A:   c++ library containing class Account - can not touch classes, just use them. 
libraryB: c library having struct Account - can not touch anything there.
my file: include lib A, lib B, from lib B get info about account and pass into lib A and do some operation on information...

Comment: If I understand correctly you did not write the C++ class yourself? It is not your code? If that is true then there's not a lot you can do.

Comment: Nope, if you depend on third party code then there's not a lot you can do but to stick to what that code has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do would be to add a conversion constructor to the class:

```
Account::Account(const account& a){
    account_number = a.account_number;
    name = a.name;
    balance = a.balance;
}
```

This will mean you will be able to use an `account` where the rest of your program expects an `Account`. The next most simple way of doing this would be to write a function to convert between the types, which you might do if you weren't able to change the implementation of `Account`.